# import file and convert too pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Using python and pandas i want to achieve the following:

i have about 600 json files with the following file format:

```
User Name: ǝuuǝıɹpɐ\nAll Tags: Delightful Followers\t|\tlibtards\t........|\tExpressionEngine\t|\t\nYour Tag:
```

i want to create a pandas DataFrame for all the files and have it look like this

```
User name     All Tags                                       Your tag
ǝuuǝıɹpɐ     Delightful Followers\t|\tlibtards\t....
.             .                        
.             .
```

i tried usign the following code:

```
 data = pd.read_csv('D:/datasets/edx1/word_cloud/557563.json', sep="\n", header=None)
```

which gives me the following DataFrame

```
0   User Name: ǝuuǝıɹpɐ
1   All Tags: Delightful Followers\t|\tlibtards\t|...
2   Your Tag:
```

Also im not sure why the json file looks the way it does, reading online it says that json files are dictionaries but it doesnt seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

1) Iterate over files, for instance by using `os.listdir()` on the input directory: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

2) for each file, `open` (exact procedure depends on your Py version) and convert the file into a Python dictionary using `json.load()` from the *json* module, [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load). This will turn the `json` into a standard `dict`.

3) you can convert these dictionaries into pandas `DataFrame`s by using `from_dict()` : [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).

Comment: I don't think its a `json` format, take a look on example in the question.

Comment: yes, so the file type says that its json but the format does not resemble it at all, i have been using open('filename') to import them.

Comment: @sKwa Dang indeed. I did not look at it that closely. good call.

Comment: @AasheetKumar Yes so if it's not actual JSON the `load()` will not work.